# material prebuilt theme not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular-material

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^15.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
```

above are the dependencies of my application from `package.json`

my angular component html code is as below

```
<mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
                <input type="text" matInput formControlName="firstName" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
                    placeholder="First Name">

                <mat-error
                    *ngIf="profileForm.controls['firstName'].errors?.required && profileForm.controls['firstName'].errors?.touched">
                    First Name is <strong>required</strong>
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
```

// app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { TemplateDrivenComponent } from './template-driven/template-driven.component';
import { ReactiveComponent } from './reactive/reactive.component';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

import { CdkAccordionModule } from '@angular/cdk/accordion';
import { MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    TemplateDrivenComponent,
    ReactiveComponent
  ],
  exports: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    CdkAccordionModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: { appearance: 'outline' } }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I'm including material theme in `angular.json` file

"styles": [
"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
"src/styles.scss",
"node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/pink-bluegrey.css"
],

Problem I'm facing is, when the application loaded the material input don't have any border, which gives an impression than, there is no input field at all.
but when the focus is on input field, the border appears.

What I am looking for is, there must be a border by default -- which is the default behavior of material theme -- for the material input field.

Screenshots.

Form while page load - fields are not visible
[image]

field after focus on field 1 - mandatory field

[image]

field after focus on field 2 - optional field

[image]

Comment: can you share a screenshot of that input field without any border please?

Comment: Might be an issue in the order of the stylesheets in the angular.json styles array or you can try to import the material theme style you want into the styles.css file (as a workaround until you find the source of the styles absence)

Comment: `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"` - there is the possibility of Bootstrap _overridding_ the styles that Angular Material sets in their own stylesheet. The best alternative would be to either use an utility-class based approach such as [TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com/), or to apply only what you need from Bootstrap's CSS via their [SCSS theming](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/customize/sass/).

Comment: @LuigiWoodhouse added screenshots

Comment: @JordiRiera tried both ways. ie; adding css at angular.json as well as styles.scss file. both are giving same behavior. Also tried only with theme file, without any other css files. no luck.

Comment: @Edric tried after removing bootstrap.css . same behavior.

Comment: Try adding  import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; to your app.module.ts file.